# Is there a way to differentiate user from user-initiated systematic field value changes in field history?

Tags: visual-workflow, field-history, audit-fields

I'm working in an org that is highly regulated and has multiple systematic field changes that happen as a result of a user making a single field change.

For example, when an opportunity stage switches from New to In Progress, the probability is systematically changed from 25% to 50% and the owner is reassigned based on some custom logic that was written on an Apex trigger.

We have field history tracking enabled for opportunities and can see the three changes in that history, but they all show the user as the user who made the stage change, when in reality, the user changed the status and the two other fields were systematically changed as part of that status change.

Is there any Salesforce object/field enablement within history that would capture systematic vs human field changes? Is there anyway to change the default user for systematic changes so that difference would be clear of the user changed the status, but the system changed the other two fields?

I'm struggling to find anything that covers this and find it difficult to believe that SF would not provide functionality to differentiate between the two updates.

NOTE: We do have Salesforce shield.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best solution for your case but you can use Platform Events.
"when an opportunity stage switches from New to In Progress" you can publish your custom Platform Event and then handle it in Event Trigger where Probability and Owner can be changed. Those actions in Event Trigger will be running on behalf of 'Automated Process' user.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383103&type=1